# Required information on work item, before a ticket is added to iteration

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-boards

I'd like to make sure, that all required fields in my tickets are filled properly, before a specific work item will be part of the current sprint / iteration.

**Detailed explanation:**

- The work item in Azrue DevOps shall have some required fields like "Problem description" / "Current situation"
- The required fields of the work item doesn't need to be filled, if the work item is created and only pushed to backlog
- Once the work item will be moved from backlog to current iteration, it shall be checked if the required fields are filled. If these fields are not filled, a movement to the sprint shall be prevented and the user (who wants to add the ticket to current iteration) shall be informed that required fields needs to be filled

Can this be done in AzureDevops?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can this be done in AzureDevops?

As far as I know, there is no such feature in Azure DevOps can meet your requirements.

In Azure DevOps, we can use the [work item rule](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/custom-rules?view=azure-devops) to set the required value when the work item moves.

This is very close to your needs. However, currently Azure DevOps does not support adding an iteration path field to the work item rules.

[image]

So there is no out-of-box method could meet your requirements now.

Here is a suggestion ticket about [Add Iteration Path to Rules](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/allow-work-item-rules-to-set-iteration-path/786946), you can refer to it.